# Sending video file in API

Tags: android, api

I need to make API in Json to send the video. I don't want to send the path of video. What is the best way to send the video in JSON which will be used by android and iPhone guys. If I use the base64 or byte[] then I am getting the memory exception error.

Comment: byte is the best way, I think. Please post your codes and errors logs...

Comment: byte is working on web but when I try to send it through Json it gives error for memory exception.

Comment: Are trying to load the complete file in your memory at once? You maybe need to split it in chunks otherwise if the file is too big.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I do it in chunks and how will we fetch it in android and make it video again?

Comment: Research "streaming".

Comment: Sending base64 media files via JSON is exactly the opposite way of API intention. And why are you trying to do that in the first way?

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File("video.mp4");

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
try {
    for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {
         bos.write(buf, 0, readNum); //no doubt here is 0
         System.out.println("read " + readNum + " bytes,");
     }
 } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(genJpeg.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 }
 byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
```

This is how you add a video byte by byte inside an byte array. You just then send the byte array as JSONOBject by following...

```
byte[] data; //array holding the video
String base64Encoded = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(data); //You have encoded the array into String

now send that to server. (I am guessing you know how to)..
```

This is how you will decode your JSON to byteArray again.

```
byte[] base64Decoded = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64Encoded);
```

The typical way to send binary in json is to base64 encode it. Java provides different ways to Base64 encode and decode a byte[]. One of these is DatatypeConverter.

I hope it helps. 
Cheers!

Edited:
You are getting OutOfMemoryException, because HeapMemory is 2Mb in size and your video is 2Mb, so when inserting into String, it's going out of memory. Even if you put it into an Object instances, you will EITHER have to re-initialize the heap or some way else. I will try to write an answer tomorrow. (Writing this half asleep, might be other way around_

Comment: String base64Encoded = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(data);  gives the memory exception error. It is making too long string that memory exception is coming. My video is 2 MB size.