# reactjs 415 unsupported media type

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, http-post

I am calling post api from react -

```js
fetch(url, {
    method : 'POST',
    body : JSON.stringify(payload),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        'Accept' : 'application/json',
    },
    
 })
 .then(response => console.log(response))
 .catch(error => console.error(error))
```

But I am receiving error -

```
415 Unsupported mediatype
```

I tried with

```
'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

But this also not worked.

Api is responding 200 with expected json output when hit from swagger.

Comment: Its important to have a look on your controller defination, could you please include that? In addition, how the `payload` constructed could please confirm?

Comment: Depending on the type of the payload the api request can get rejected. If anything make sure your payload is a blob or a stream of binary data ( if it's a [video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39873654/sending-video-file-in-api) )